# My M1 MBP doesn't let me boot into my Ubuntu Installer USB. I tried rEFInd but I couldn't mount my EFI drive

Tags: usb, startup, install

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my 64GB USB. I used Unetbootin to install an aarch64 Ubuntu 20.10 ISO to my USB.

When I restart into Startup Options, I only see "Options" and "Macintosh HD".

I decided to try and use rEFInd, but I can't mount the EFI drive. So now I have 2 problems, the main one would be trying to install rEFInd but the second one would be trying to boot into the installer.

How to I mount my M1 Mac's EFI drive (so that I can use rEFInd to boot into the Ubuntu Installer)?

I've done some research and looked into this, and it seems that people are saying the M1 Mac doesn't use any EFI stuff so I guess I'd have to wait for something to come out for the M1 Mac, which sucks.

All I want to do is just boot into my USB, I don't care what it is (Ubuntu x64 installer, arm installer, I don't care!), I just want to see something different.

M1 MBP - 8GB RAM - Big Sur 11.3

Comment: Ubuntu has an Apple Silicon build?  An ARM build, sure.  But something that's actually bootable on Apple Silicon?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but there is an [aarch64 iso](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-arm64.iso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Silicon macs have a different booting process and devices that need drivers and no current Linux distribution works on it.

The [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/about/) project is working on getting a Linux working on a M1 machine. Until that works to run Linux you have to use a virtual machine.

For why you need a special Linux I think this is a starting point https://github.com/AsahiLinux/docs/wiki/Introduction-to-Apple-Silicon